# issues while uploading django on vps

Tags: django, hosting, vps

I have a Django project with postgersql latest and models , and I want to deploy it on a Contabo server VPS Hosting , I installed Cpanel, but it gives me a lot of issues, for example:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial completely like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#configure-settings-py? For example did you add `django.contrib.gis` to your installed_apps?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is basically tellling you the answer, your current database configuration in the settings file is incorrect.There's probably a typo in how you've declared the db in the settings file. Correct that and then your error should be gone.